# R not converting to numeric

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have a matrix of information that I import from  tab separated files. Once I import this data, I consolidate it in to a dataframe, and perform some editing on it to make it usable.

The last step, is for me to convert all the numbers to numeric. In order to do this, i use
as.numeric(as.character()). Unfortunately, the numbers do not change to numeric. They are still of chr type.
Here is my code:

```
   stringsAsFactors=F
filelist <- list.files(path="C:\\Users\\LocalAdmin\\Desktop\\Correlation Project\\test", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
temp <- data.frame()
TSV <- data.frame()
for (i in seq (1:length(filelist)))
{
    temp <- read.table(file=filelist[i],head=TRUE,sep="\t")
    TSV <- rbind(TSV,temp)
}


for (i in seq(15,1,-1))  #getting rid of extraneous dataframe entries
{
    TSV <- TSV[-i,] #deleting by row
}

for(i in seq(1,ncol(TSV),1))
{
    TSV[,i] <- as.numeric(as.character(TSV[,i]))
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Even with your code, it's hard for us to know what's going on without having the actual data. What's the output of `class(TSV[,1])`? If you could post the output of `dput(head(TSV[,1]))`, that would also be useful - it would let us recreate a small chunk of the TSV object.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example and remove all the unneeded stuff. Also,why are you using for-loops?

Comment: @EDi I'll clean up the code and upload another version. I am using the for loop to go through the database, and remove any columns that begin with 'b''a''l' or 'u'. I do this because these columns contain information that I don't require.

Comment: @MattParker The resultant data frame is basically several names on the first column, and the rest of the columns are just decimal numbers. Here is the output you had requested: structure(c("-1.26", "-1.94", "0.5", "-1.79", "0.55", "1.45"), .Names = c("S9_Z", 
"S4_Y", "H4_X", "H_O", "L461_L", "H4_Z".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JPC I finally managed to get this to work. Here is my code:

```
TSVnew<-apply(TSV,2,as.numeric)
rownames(TSVnew)<-rownames(TSV)
TSV<-TSVnew
```

However, I still don't understand why my previous attempt using this didn't work:

```
for(i in seq(1,ncol(TSV),1))
{
    TSV[,i] <- as.numeric(as.character(TSV[,i]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
TSV <- as.data.frame(as.numeric(as.matrix(TSV)))
```

This will only work if all values can be transformed into numbers.

Comment: I'll write up some code to clean up all non numeric entries, and let you know if this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here:

Prefer vector operations whenever possible

no need to read the files in a for loop

```
TSV<-do.call(rbind,lapply(filelist, read.delim))
```

your loop to get rid of extraneous info can be reduced to a vector operation

```
TSV<-TSV[-(1:15),]
```

I'm assuming you are getting factors and integers that you want as numeric

```
oldClasses<-sapply(TSV[1,],class)
int2numeric<-oldClasses == "integer"
factor2numeric<-oldClasses == "factor"

TSV[,int2numeric]<-as.numeric(TSV[,int2numeric])
TSV[,factor2numeric]<-as.numeric(as.character(TSV[,factor2numeric]))
```

you could arguably reduce the 2 above to one, but I think this makes your intent clear

and that should be it

Comment: Thanks for your help, the code has made my script much more efficient. However, all elements of TSV are of 'chr' type. I tried converting these using sapply(TSV,as.numeric) and it didn't convert them to numeric.Also, why are you doing this?oldClasses<-sapply(TSV[1,],class)

Comment: This is my TSV dataframe: chr [1:54, 1:3] "-1.26" "-1.94" "0.50" "-1.79" "0.55" "1.45" "-3.74" "-1.85" "1.35" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:54] "S4_Y" "S42_Y" "H46_X" "H46" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "862421" "862439" "862738"

Comment: I didn't know all your columns where chr, so I wanted to save down the classes and then be able to look up which columns where integer/factor and convert to numeric accordingly. Rather than lookup the column types twice, I saved it down as a variable.

mmm...what do you mean by not converting them to numeric? Does it fail? Do they remain as character? Does it introduce NAs?

Comment: Thats cool. I didn't know you could do that. They all remain as characters, as if I had never tried to convert them. I have found a solution though! Pl. check my answer on this thread. Thanks!